# Trying to save keywords from a .txt file to an array and use that array to search another doc for the keywords

Tags: python, arrays, loops, python-3.x, arraylist

I am trying to save a bunch of keywords in a file called keywordtest.txt containing words such as `networkmanager`, `filemanager` and `speaker` etc. (Each on its own line in the .txt file).

I have got it to save the words into an array but I then want it to use the words stored in that array to search in another document called test and bring up the whole line that the keywords was found in and store that line in another doc called results.txt.

I have managed to get it to search using the words in the array and save them to another file but will only find something if it is not contained in a line:

For example, I search for `networkmanager` and if it is just `networkmanager` on a line of its own in the file I am searching in it will find it, but if its like 'I am a networkmanager' for example it wont pick it up.

```
#!\usr\bin\python

x = []

with open("keywordtest.txt","r") as y:
    for line in y:
        x.append(line)
print x

theFile = open ("results.txt", "w")
searchfile = open("test", "r")

for line in searchfile:
    for word in x: 
    if word in line: 
    theFile.write(line)

theFile.close()
searchfile.close()
```

**EDIT:** the code i posted was a version of me when trying something out, i seen online someone using 'word' instead of 'line' in some places and tried it out but it didnt like it, the code below is the code i have got to work but only displays the ekywords i am searching for if they are on their own.

```
#!\usr\bin\python

x = []

with open("keywordtest.txt","r") as y:
    for line in y:
        x.append(line)
print x


theFile = open ("results.txt", "w")
searchfile = open("test", "r")

for line in searchfile:
    if line in x: theFile.write(line)
    if line in x: print line

theFile.close()
searchfile.close()
```

Comment: at last you want results.txt file with the matched words ???

Answer (score 0):

```
    #!\usr\bin\python

x = []

with open("keywordtest.txt","r") as y:
    for line in y:
        x.append(line)
print x

theFile = open ("results.txt", "w")
searchfile = open("test.txt", "r")

for line in searchfile:
    for word in x: 
        if word in line.strip():
            theFile.write(word)

theFile.close()
searchfile.close()
```

Comment: sorry guys made a mistake with the code i posted, it was an older trial and error version that wasn't working. If you could take a look at the code i have now put as it works when searching for a word one its own but wont find it if that would is in a line. sorry and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

based on your edit:

```
#!\usr\bin\python
x = []

with open("keywordtest.txt","r") as y:
    for line in y:
        x.append(line)
print x


theFile = open ("results.txt", "w")
searchfile = open("test.txt", "r")

for line in searchfile:
    for item in x:
        if item in line: 
            theFile.write(line)
            print line

theFile.close()
searchfile.close()
```

This saves the matched words in theFile.txt and will print out the matches assuming keywordtest.txt has only one word per line same as test.txt

Comment: this has pulled up everything in my test file even if its not one of my keywords contained in the array

Comment: @JamesB123 can you give an example of what these files contain?